# How to pass more than one argument to a function in views.py, also using only one of the arguments in the regex expression?

Tags: python, django

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><a href="{% url 'record_and_play' nameOnly no_of_frames %}" style="color: white;">GO!</a></button>
```

Function definition in Views.py:

```
def record_and_play(request, nameOnly, no_of_frames):
    # ...
return render(request, 'processing/start.html', soundFile)
```

And relevant code in urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
url('^process/$', views.create, name='process-page'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/', views.parseData, name='start'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/', views.record_and_play, name='record_and_play'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/new/', views.parseData, name='start-new'),
]
```

It works when I use something like this (`?f=` is arbitrary) in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url('^process/$', views.create, name='process-page'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/', views.parseData, name='start'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/?f=(?P<no_of_frames>\d+)/', views.record_and_play, name='record_and_play'),
url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/new/', views.parseData, name='start-new'),
]
```

Comment: well your question is unclear. First if you want to pass a parameter in the button is something like nameOnly='Your_parameter_here', why do you put no_of_frames if doesn't exist

Comment: Both the arguments: nameOnly and no_of_frames exist and have valid values.

Comment: you could do it with query parameters or get or post parameters using hidden form element.

Comment: just delete the ?f=, url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w)/ is different to this url('^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/(?P<no_of_frames>\d+)/

Comment: I need only '^process/start/(?P<nameOnly>\w+)/' for both name='start' and name='record_and_play'.